# .gitignore is not ignoring file "login.php"

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file in my repo.

```
#DB Ignore
db_connect.php

#Environment Banner
template.php

#LDAP - ldap_start_tls() error
login.php
```

However, it is not ignoring the changes I make to "login.php". Both "db_connect.php" and "template.php" ignore just fine. Any idea as to why this is happening?

As a side note, in vi, the word "log" in "login.php" is highlighted in orange.

Comment: Maybe this is more what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11366713/677381

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/636762

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you've committed this file already to the repository, and so Git will be tracking the changes on it. You will have to remove the file using `git rm` before it will ignore it.